# Get rid of XAML Window from Taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a XAML window that I show with ShowDialog, is there a way to make it (not) appear in the taskbar?

The problem is that I can set the window to be topmost but if that window opens another dialog and I set that also to be topmost, I can put the second behind the first by clicking in the taskbar.  This tends to confuse users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your child window, set the [ShowInTaskbar property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showintaskbar.aspx) to false.

Comment: Yeah I guess there really is no substitute for reading the intellisense is there?  Thanks @Tim